# How can i redirect the url keeping key value

Tags: php, html

I have web site (wish.com) and ssl encripted accounts server (wish111.com). I'm using wish.com for advertising and information purpose. I redirected the url of registration and login pages from wish.com to wish111.com. All the time i prefer to hiding the link of wish111.com for consumer usage.

But i'm facing a problem on consumer account activation link. I'm getting the link to activate together wish111.com/activate.php?key=c1af2cfa9aq . I can change the domain name of activation link as wish.com/activate.php?key=$

how can i redirect the link using key value

Comment: just change the line which gives the link output?

Comment: key value is variable to consumer activation

Comment: i understand. but as the question stands now, you want to change `wish111.com` to `wish.com` (I am excluding the rest part becuase it is same). The above part is not variable.

Comment: Activation link is a part of activate the consumer account. I can modify the link with any domain name for activation email. But proper link needed to activate the php (wish111.com/activate.php?key=$)

Comment: Activation link is a part of activate the consumer account. I can modify the link with any domain name for activation email. But proper link needed to activate the php (wish111.com/activate.php?key=$) So im expecting the code to redirect the link with key value. Eg. wish.com/activate.php?key=c1af2cfa9aq --> wish111.com/activate.php?key=c1af2cfa9aq            c1af2cfa9aq is variable , will change to change consumer registration

Comment: I don't think we understand what you're asking for.  There seems to be a language barrier here.  Can you try showing some code example or maybe presenting the problem differently?

Comment: ex : www.wish.com/activate.php?key=c1af2cfa9aq => www.wish111.com/search.php?c1af2cfa9aq 

ex : www.wish.com/activate.php?key=a231dfc12asa => www.wish111.com/activate.php?key=a231dfc12asa

need php code..

Comment: If i understood what you want, you need htaccess file with appropriate RewriteRule.

Comment: Any ideas on which rewrite rules to use?

Comment: htaccess file with appropriate RewriteRule please..